# JPEG corrupted after sending via HTTP

Tags: java, http

I'm trying to build a simple HTTP Java server from scratch.
Right now I am trying to get my browser to download a .jpg-file on my PC,
that's why 
The fo`image/jpeg` is hardcoded into the method. The following is the method printing the HTTP-response to my browser. `desiredFile` a .jpg file called "Image.jpg" stored on my Computer.

Everything works great and my broser downloads the file, but I cannot open it. The Windows Image Program just tells me that it's "probably damaged". When I view the image's details I can see that it has the same byte-size, but details such as resolution are lost.  `

```
        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(desiredFile.toPath());

        System.out.println("Attempting to print to client|" + bytes.length

        output.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK" + "\r\n"
                        + "Content-type: image/jpeg" + "\r\n"
                        + "Content-length: " + bytes.length + "\r\n"
                        + "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Imae.jpg" + "\r\n"
                        + "\r\n");

        for (byte currentByte : bytes)
            output.write(currentByte);

        output.flush();
        output.close();

        System.out.println("Printing finished.");
        `
```

Is there something wrong with the way I am transmitting the bytes? Sending `bytes`as a whole array did not work, that is why I am sending every byte after the other.

Thanks!

Comment: `"Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Imae.jpg" + "\r\n"` is this a typo? Do you mean `Image.jpg`?

Comment: Please show how "output" is declared and opened

Comment: Are you using `InputStreamReader` by any chance to read the bytes?

Comment: @Ishnark Oh, yes, that was a typo, my bad, haha. @Joni "output" was a `PrintWriter`, which I now corrected to a `DataOutputStream`. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using an `OutputWriter`.

Your bytes will be interpreted as characters, which in turn are encoded as different bytes. For example, with UTF-8, sending the byte `0x80` will result in the two bytes `0xC2 0x80`. This trashes the image.

The fact that you weren't able to send the full array directly is a huge red flag: this should obviously work. If it doesn't, you should find out why. The error message probably mentioned that it expected `char[]` instead of `byte[]`, indicating that your source is character based instead of byte based.

To fix it, switch to a `PrintStream`. It allows you to both output String for the header and `byte[]` for the body.

Comment: Yes, I changed it to a DataOutputStream which finally worked. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but you might be missing the header:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```